# Click on close element using selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium and web development. I am working on a project to take screenshots from the websites from [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org).

Here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220315011343/https://stackoverflow.com/) to the sample webpage. I am trying to click on the close button (on the top right of this page) before capturing the screenshots. I am not sure what kind of element is the **close button** and I was unsuccessful in my attempts.

Here is the element I am attempting to click from selenium:
[image: example illustrated in a screenshot]

Here is the corresponding HTML

```
<a id="wm-tb-close" href="#close" style="top:-2px;" title="Close the toolbar"><span class="iconochive-remove-circle" style="color:#888888;font-size:240%;"></span></a>
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.binary_location = "<path-to-local-dir>/google-chrome/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20220315011343/https://stackoverflow.com/')

# My attempts at closing the wayback toolbar:
# driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'close').click()    # Attempt 1
# driver.find_element(By.ID, 'wm-tb-close').click() # Attempt 2
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[@title='Close the toolbar']").click() # Attempt 3

# Capture full webpage screenshot (with scrolling)
original_size = driver.get_window_size()
# required_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
required_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(1920, max(required_height, 1080))
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').screenshot('webpage_screenshot.png')  # avoids scrollbar
driver.set_window_size(original_size['width'], original_size['height'])  # reset to defaults

driver.quit()
```

When I make an attempt to click on the close button using the three techniques (shown in the code), I receive the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element

Comment: Is the element rendered to the DOM when you attempt to click it? If not, you may need to time.sleep() your code to give the DOM time to render.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Thanks, I just tested my code by adding `time.sleep(10)` immediately following the `driver.get(...)`. I still receive the same error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to click is inside the SHADOW-ROOT, to access such elements you need to use some special techniques.
Also you need to use Expected Conditions explicit waits to let the elements loaded before accessing them.
This should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.binary_location = "<path-to-local-dir>/google-chrome/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20220315011343/https://stackoverflow.com/')
#locate the shadow root element
root_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "wm-ipp-base")))
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root_element)
#access the close button inside the shadow root
shadow_root.find_element_by_css_selector("span.iconochive-remove-circle").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the Shadow-root. This is new, I need to learn about it. I am however receiving error when I run the code - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'`.

Comment: That means `shadow_root` object was not created correctly. Please let me know if `root_element` element is of type webelement or NoneType?

Comment: `root_element` is of type `WebElement`

Comment: That's good. So the problem is with shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root_element)

Comment: Try this explanations: https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html

Comment: I looked into the code, however, it did not help. I think the issue is the element we are trying to access is inside **shadow-root (closed)**. If it was **(open)** then the above solution would have worked. I need to do further investigation on how to handle this case.

Comment: Selecting the element by ID `wm-ipp-base` followed by `clicking` this element, and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> a fixed number of times and pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, I was able to programatically click on close. I had to follow this workaround since the shadow-root is **closed**.

Comment: I also think it may be caused by closed shadow-root. Actually I never worked with shadow-root elements so all I can do here is to search existing answers and tutorials as you can. I'm sorry I could not actually resolve your problem, but I see you are experienced enough programmer so I believe you will find a solution. So I'd like to ask you: when you find a solution - please post an asnwer here and please let me know. Thank you in advance!